# AVD Manager loses user-created device definitions after closing and reopening itself

Tags: android, xml, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I create a new device definition in AVD Manager, I can create a new AVD with this device definition.
If I close and reopen AVD Manager, the device definition is lost and the AVD created gets "repairable" status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a locale specific bug. We are discussing it on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/nfJvhxO8iJk

As you pointed out, a temporary fix is to create the device definition, then edit `~/android/devices.xml` and replace commas with dots.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this issue by opening my devices.xml, where device definition are stored, and replacing every comma ',' with a dot '.'

```
<d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
<d:diagonal-length>3,70</d:diagonal-length>
<d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
<d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
<d:dimensions>
    <d:x-dimension>480</d:x-dimension>
    <d:y-dimension>720</d:y-dimension>
</d:dimensions>
<d:xdpi>254,00</d:xdpi>
<d:ydpi>254,00</d:ydpi>
```

>

```
<d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
<d:diagonal-length>3.70</d:diagonal-length>
<d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
<d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
<d:dimensions>
    <d:x-dimension>480</d:x-dimension>
    <d:y-dimension>720</d:y-dimension>
</d:dimensions>
<d:xdpi>254.00</d:xdpi>
<d:ydpi>254.00</d:ydpi>
```

devices.xml is located in .android\devices.xml

I realized this solution comparing a user-created device definition and a built-in Google device definition.

No idea of why AVD Manager saves user-created device definition XML this weird way.

Comment: What locale is your development machine set to, and what OS is it running? This feels like they went with locale-specific float formatting on write, but botched reading it in correctly, or something along those lines.